# How to identify model property descriptiion (lke name, type) and fault exception details from wsdl using c#

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I would much appreciate any suggestion on the following requirement.

**Problem statement:**  I need to parse a wsdl file to get properties of the data contract(model property name and type etc) as well as fault exception details. The wsdl of a service will contain details of various operations. I will pass the operation name and in return list of properties of the following data contract. If there are nested object graph , we need to grab those info as well. Kind of recursive call. another hand we need to get the fault exceptions for the passed in operation. So two separate methods basically.

Comment: Is it possible to you show parts of your code?

Comment: In VS it is possible to get properties and other details of a wsdl with adding web reference. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/creating-the-web-service-proxy?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @isaeid: Thanks for showing your interest. The coding has not started yet. I am thinking about the approach to get it done. I have a wsdl file in my hand. after selecting an operation from that wsdl(dedicated to a single service), I need the list details of data contracts of that operation and fault exception message as both are available in the wsdl file. Probbaly ServiceDescription class could be a help.